# Unable to get Stripe payment POST response with details - Swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

We've integrated Stripe payment into an iOS app and been able to process a few test payments successfully. However, when trying to retrieve the Stripe POST response, we only got the unexpected response value `SUCCESS: 0 bytes`. We expect to get a response with data similar to below. Could any of the Stripe experts here help us out? Many thanks!

Expected response:

```
{ "id": "ch_1Gk6idAVkuhdAj6ucjbpTn5p",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 54912,
   ...}
```

Code used for Stripe payment:

```swift
    static let sharedClient = StripeClient()

    var baseURLString: String? = nil

    var baseURL: URL {

        if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {

            return url
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func createAndConfirmPayment(_ token: STPToken, amount: Int, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("charge")

        let params: [String: Any] = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId, "amount": amount, "description": Constants.defaultDescription, "currency": Constants.defaultCurrency]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseData { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case.success(let value):

                //print("value is \(value)") // This is where we get 0 bytes.

                completion(nil)

            case.failure(let error):
                print("error processing the payment", error.localizedDescription)
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The response there is not coming from Stripe's API though, it's from your backend server(whatever "<baseURL>/charge" resolves to). So the first step is to investigate your own backend code and see what response it returns to the app on this route.